# Python count in a sublist in a nest list

Tags: python

```
x = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'c', 'd'], ['e', 'f', 'f']]
```

Let's say we have a list with random str letters.
How can i create a function so it tells me how many times the letter 'a' comes out, which in this case 2. Or any other letter, like 'b' comes out once, 'f' comes out twice. etc.
Thank you!

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: `sum(1 for e in x if 'a' in e)`

Comment: can you clear this up for me a bit? :/ i'm a bit new to python.

Comment: @Abhijit or just `sum('a' in e for e in x)`, which reads easier at least to me (as "add up how many of these have 'a' in them").

Answer (score 6):

You could flatten the list and use `collections.Counter`:

```
>>> import collections
>>> x = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'c', 'd'], ['e', 'f', 'f']]
>>> d = collections.Counter(e for sublist in x for e in sublist)
>>> d
Counter({'a': 2, 'c': 2, 'f': 2, 'b': 1, 'e': 1, 'd': 1})
>>> d['a']
2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import itertools, collections
result = collections.defaultdict(int)
for i in itertools.chain(*x):
    result[i] += 1
```

This will create `result` as a dictionary with the characters as keys and their counts as values.

Comment: You could also just do `collections.Counter(itertools.chain(*x))`, as the `Counter` class does the same thing as you just did.

Comment: @Blender thanks; I thought `Counter` was python 3.1+, but I see in the docs it says 2.7.  Regardless the computer I was testing on is 2.6 :/

Comment: Instead of `itertools.chain(*x)` it's preferable to use `chain.from_iterable(x)`

Answer (score 0):

Just FYI, you can use `sum()` to flatten a single nested list.

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>>
>>> x = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'c', 'd'], ['e', 'f', 'f']]
>>> c = Counter(sum(x, []))
>>> c
Counter({'a': 2, 'c': 2, 'f': 2, 'b': 1, 'e': 1, 'd': 1})
```

But, as Blender and John Clements have addressed, `itertools.chain.from_iterable()` may be more clear.

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> c = Counter(chain.from_iterable(x)))
>>> c
Counter({'a': 2, 'c': 2, 'f': 2, 'b': 1, 'e': 1, 'd': 1})
```

Comment: `chain` can also be quite a bit faster, since `sum` builds a number of intermediate lists while `chain` builds none.