# unique count in (list of smaller lists)

Tags: python, list

Is there a pythonic way to count the elements in a list of lists preferably using collections?

```
lol = [[1,2,3],[4,2],[5,1,6]]
```

Out:

```
1: 2
2: 2
3: 1
4: 1
5: 1
6: 1
```

Comment: Anything you tried that you want to share with us?

Comment: *preferably using collections*. Presumably you already looked and found [`collections.Counter()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) then? What problems did you encounter making that work?

Comment: `sum(map(Counter, lol), Counter())`, short but slower compared to itertools version.

Comment: @sundarnatarajサンダーナタラジ Sure, but also point out that this is less efficient in comparison to itertools version.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I dont think this is a duplicate as the other question is asking for count of a single element at a time. Not all of them!

Comment: @AbhishekThakur: you'll need to address 200 OK about that one; I voted to close as 'unclear what you are asking' because your question lacked any detail as to where you were stuck.

Comment: @AbhishekThakur Did you see Imran's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5828150/846892) there? None of the answers here add nothing new to it.

Comment: @200OK, I think there's a case to be made that this is not a duplicate _of that question_. That question has an answer to this question, but that doesn't necessarily make this a duplicate of that question. However I am certain that this has been asked before.

Comment: It's also almost a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15151762/577088), and is an exact (imo) duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23098468/577088).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from collections import Counter
import itertools
a= [[1,2,3],[4,2],[5,1,6]]

print Counter(itertools.chain(*a))

#output Counter({1: 2, 2: 2, 3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 1, 6: 1})

b=Counter(itertools.chain(*a))
for key,val in b.iteritems():
    print key,':',val
```

output:

```
1 : 2
2 : 2
3 : 1
4 : 1
5 : 1
6 : 1
```

Other way of doing this but less efficient compared to itertools( thanks to 200OK)

```
a= [[1,2,3],[4,2],[5,1,6]]
sum(map(Counter, a), Counter())
#output {1: 2, 2: 2, 3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 1, 6: 1}
```

Comment: You don't need `list(...)`

Comment: `isinstance(Counter(), dict)`

Comment: @200OK what is above comment. i dint get it.

Comment: @sundarnatarajサンダーナタラジ `Counter` is a subclass of `dict`, so instead of `b=dict(Counter(itertools.chain(*a))) for ... in b` you can simply `for key,val in Counter(itertools.chain(*a))` without creating another `dict`.

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import Counter
import itertools
lol = [[1,2,3],[4,2],[5,1,6]]
Counter(itertools.chain.from_iterable(lol))
```

Output

```
Counter({1: 2, 2: 2, 3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 1, 6: 1})
```